# White space at footer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I write simple website that have several pages

I have this code in my html. It works ok on normal resolutions

```css
body {
  background-image: url(../image/BKG.jpg);
  background-position: center top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'TimesNewRoman';
}

* {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.navbar {
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  min-height: 130px;
}

.navbar-default {
  background: none;
  color: none;
}

.navbar-header {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.navbar-brand {
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar-brand img {
  display: block;
}

.navbar-nav {
  margin-top: 64px;
}

.navbar-nav>li {
  font-size: 26px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  padding: 20px 38px;
  color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar-nav>li>a:hover::after,
.navbar-nav>li>a.active::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 31px;
  left: -10px;
  background-image: url(../image/Arrow_left.png);
  background-size: 100%;
  width: 44px;
  height: 3px;
}

.navbar-nav>li>a:hover::before,
.navbar-nav>li>a.active::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 31px;
  right: -10px;
  background-image: url(../image/Arrow_right.png);
  background-size: 100%;
  width: 44px;
  height: 3px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:link {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #ffffff;
}

.container.text {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 32px;
  padding: 70px 9% 50px;
  margin-top: 9%;
}

.container.text img {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.container.text p {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.container.text.contacts p {
  margin-bottom: 77px;
}

.container.text.disclaimer {
  padding: 15px 50px;
}

.container-fluid.footer {
  box-shadow: 0 -40px 40px -20px black inset;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.container.footer {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.container.footer a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    background-size: cover;
  }
  .navbar-brand {
    width: 80%;
  }
  .navbar-toggle {
    margin-top: 11%;
  }
}

.fix {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="image/Logo_cutted.png" alt="logo" /></a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="contact_us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://crescentcovecapital.fileshare.com" target="_blank">Investor Login</a></li>
          <li><a href="about_us.html">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
  <!-- /.navbar navbar-default -->

  <footer style="height:auto;" class="container-fluid footer">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="container footer">
        Copyright © 2017 Crescent Cove. All Rights reserved. <a href="#">Disclaimer</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
```

it works ok, but when I minimize my window I have white space in bottom of page

[image]

how I can fix it?

Thank's for help.

Comment: What do you want instead of the white space at the bottom?

Comment: picture background @ikkuh

Comment: Use `viewport` units `height:100vh`

Comment: It helps. thank's!!!!@LokeshGupta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update css part

```
body {
  background-image: url(../image/BKG.jpg);
  background-position: center top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 100vh;  /* Add this */
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'TimesNewRoman';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your body:

```
body{
    background: url(YOURIMG.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

Comment: it still white :(

Comment: I still see this white space. What info I can provide?

Comment: What white space are we talking about, I don't see white spaces when I run my edited version.

Comment: I provide screenshot at my question

Comment: That one big white space should be fixed by adding `background-size: cover` and `background-position: center center` to your code, which was what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: But it not fixing it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147444/discussion-between-logan-and-tripledeal).